# What "type" of continuous-time math is this?

Tags: continuity

I'm interested in learning more about continuous-time modeling in economics. I've been studying a recent paper in economics that models a simple control problem that yields the following equation:

$$C_t = \bar C \exp \left( - \frac{1}{\gamma} \int_t^\infty (r_s - \rho) ds \right)$$

I understand how this equation is derived. In the paper, the authors claim (without any derivations) that is is equivalent to:

$$ d \log C_t = - \frac{1}{\gamma} \int_t^\infty d r_s ds $$

I'm a novice with continuous-time models and I'm at a loss as to how this derivation is completed. More than that, I'm not even sure what "type" of operation I should be trying to learn. This looks to me like a total differential combined with Liebniz rule, but I would like a solid reference.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
d \ln C_t = \frac{C_t'}{C_t}
$$
and
$$
C_t'
 = C_t \frac{d}{dt}
  \left[- \frac{1}{\gamma} \int_t^\infty (r_s - \rho) ds\right]
 = -\frac{1}{\gamma}
   \frac{d}{dt} \left[\int_t^\infty (r_s - \rho) ds\right]
$$